Keras-NLP Albert Finetuning - Resource localhost/_0_SentencepieceOp/N10tensorflow4text12_GLOBAL__N_121SentencepieceResourceE does not exist
Describe the bug
I am fine-tuning the Keras implementation of Albert for my dataset for a classification problem by following the documentations present here - https://keras.io/api/keras_nlp/models/albert/albert_classifier/
The gist of how I am creating the model and fitting it is given below:
model = keras_nlp.models.AlbertClassifier.from_preset(
           'albert_extra_extra_large_en_uncased',
            preprocessor=keras_nlp.models.AlbertPreprocessor.from_preset(
            'albert_extra_extra_large_en_uncased',
            sequence_length=128,
        ),
            num_classes=len(self.classes.keys()),
            load_weights=True,
            activation='softmax',
        )
model.backbone.trainable = False
model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y)

When the fitting process runs, it always errors out with the stacktrace shown below. I am suspecting it must be related to SentencePiece not getting detected somehow based on the error message.
What might be doing wrong here? Am I missing something obvious?
2024-04-11 04:32:58.042517: I tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:421] Local rendezvous recv item cancelled. Key hash: 5086726160540042098
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/bot_projects/incident-classification/train.py", line 27, in <module>
    albert.AlBERTClassifier().train()
  File "/mnt/d/bot_projects/incident-classification/models/albert.py", line 67, in train
    stats = self.model.fit(x=x.tolist(), y=y.tolist(), validation_data=(t_x.tolist(), t_y.tolist()), batch_size=self.conf['modelParams']['albert']['batchSize'],
  File "/root/classifier/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_nlp/src/utils/pipeline_model.py", line 188, in fit
    return super().fit(
  File "/root/classifier/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/root/classifier/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node albert_preprocessor/albert_tokenizer/SentenceTokenizer/SentencepieceTokenizeOp defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
Detected at node albert_preprocessor/albert_tokenizer/SentenceTokenizer/SentencepieceTokenizeOp defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) NOT_FOUND:  Resource localhost/_0_SentencepieceOp/N10tensorflow4text12_GLOBAL__N_121SentencepieceResourceE does not exist.
         [[{{node albert_preprocessor/albert_tokenizer/SentenceTokenizer/SentencepieceTokenizeOp}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
         [[IteratorGetNext/_6]]
  (1) NOT_FOUND:  Resource localhost/_0_SentencepieceOp/N10tensorflow4text12_GLOBAL__N_121SentencepieceResourceE does not exist.
         [[{{node albert_preprocessor/albert_tokenizer/SentenceTokenizer/SentencepieceTokenizeOp}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_17437]

Expected behavior
The Albert preprocessor is able to detect sentence piece and use it for its preprocessing tasks,
Additional context
Things I have tried to fix it but with no success :

Uninstall and reinstall sentencepiece
Downgrade tensorflow-text to 2.15.1

I expected the Albert preprocessor is able to detect sentence piece and use it for its preprocessing tasks.
Things I have tried to fix it but with no success :

Uninstall and reinstall sentencepiece
Downgrade tensorflow-text to 2.15.1

